# Excel VBA - Needing help importing date from one column to another and then adding in a value for blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, module

I am a VBA novice who has inherited a Macro Workbook from an intern no longer around. I have been poking around with it, and feel like I'm doing a cha cha. Few steps forward and back, and I've gone in a big circle.

The code in this section worked until an update on our SharePoint site and it is now spitting out a date matching today's date. Since the field in SharePoint is now hidden (and they aren't getting rid of it in the Macro Workbook because the powers that be have decided it might be used later in the future), this date cannot be edited. If it is helpful for reference, this is a data export from SharePoint into Excel that is being used in a Macro Workbook.

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows:

- Populate dates from one tab to another tab whenever there is a date. When there is no date, populate the date 12/31/2018 for all null values where the data "lands."

What's problematic in the code we have now:

- The data in column I1 is bad for these purposes and should no longer be referenced. They want us to keep this column for the future. This is the column that is using "today's date when we run it."
- If I simply put 12/31/2018 in the code where (4/5/18) is right now, it doesn't fix the reference to column I1 (obviously).

Thank you, any input or suggestions would be great.

This is what we have currently:

```
Sub CheckEndDate2(x, outputRow)
dateStart = Worksheets("owssvr").range("I1").Offset(x, 0).Value
If dateStart = "" Then
    dateStart = Worksheets("owssvr").range("J1").Offset(x, 0).Value

End If

dateSelection = CDbl(CDate(dateStart))

stat = Worksheets("owssvr").range("F1").Offset(x, 0).Value
If dateSelection <= CDbl(CDate("3/20/18")) And stat <> "Held" Then
    dateSelection = CDbl(CDate("4/3/18"))
End If

Cells(outputRow, 6).Value = Format(dateSelection, "mm/dd/yy")

End Sub
```

Comment: If not using column I where will you be getting value from? And is 4/5/18 actually 4/3/18? And those hardcoded dates =BAD...Where should these come from?

Comment: Also, looks like it should possibly be a function rather than a sub. Where is dateselection declared, what do you do with it? How is the sub being called at present.....? Is dateStart a string? Please use Option Explicit at the top of your inherited modules and declare variables and their types.

Comment: And ("4/3/18") is not  necessarily where only nulls will be encountered. I think some further clarification is required on this. Some sample data and expected output would be very beneficial along with bullet point reasoning as to expected outcome.